# Data not saved into the csv.file in phone

Tags: java, android-studio, android-button

We have created three-button in the android studio (i.e., **Start, Stop Scan and Insert**) for wifi scanning purposes. When the '**Start**' button is pressed, a notification will be given '*Wifi Scan Started*' and the apps will scan all the wifi. After a certain period of Wifi scanning, the '**Stop Scan**' button is pressed and another notification comes up '*Wifi Scan stopped*'.  Finally, the '**Insert**' button is pressed to save the data into the phone. However, when I pressed the '**Insert**' button, instead of the '*Data Saving...*' message comes up, it showed '*Stop Scanning*'. The Wifi Scanning still going on and did not stop. When I checked the CSV. data in the external storage, it showed 0 bytes of data. The folder is created but there is no data on it, What could be wrong?

```
        Button startWifiScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
        startWifiScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.groundTruth);
                CeLLiD = editText.getText().toString();
                if(CeLLiD.equals(""))
                {
                    alert("Ground Truth is not Set");
                }
                else if(ismeasure == true)
                    alert("Scanning is already started!");
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi Scan started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    rssDatabase = dumpDataToHashmap(1);
                    sdDatabase = dumpDataToHashmap(0);
                    onResume();
                    ismeasure = true;
                    isRecord = false;
                }}
        });

        Button stopWifiScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);
        stopWifiScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi Scan stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(ismeasure == false) alert("Start Scanning!");
                else {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Testing" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second+":"+CeLLiD);
                    folder.mkdir();
                    String csv = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/data.csv";
                    try { file_writer = new FileWriter(csv, true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    onStop(); }
            }
        });

        Button insert= (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertbutton);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(ismeasure == true)
                    alert("Stop Scanning!");
                else if(ismeasure == false && isRecord == true) alert("Start Scanning!");
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saving.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        writeToCsv();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The view XML file

```xml
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="387dp"
            android:layout_height="456dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="3dp">
    
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/wifiTable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.857"
            tools:ignore="UnknownId">
    
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/groundTruth"
                android:layout_width="109dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="8"
                android:hint="      x  ,   y  "
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/startbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/groundTruth"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:text="Start" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stopbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/groundTruth"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:text="STOP SCAN" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/insertbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stopbutton"
                android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
                android:text="Insert" />
    
        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your view as well?

Comment: Sorry, when I said that I wanted to see the view; what I meant is that I want to see the XML file (the view); I worry that the ID for the "Insert button" and the "Stop Scan" button is duplicated somehow or wrong; causing the insert button to call the function

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir, the XML code is attached

Comment: Regarding your variables; ismeasure is true when you're recording, and isRecord is true when you have finished recording right? I can't help but notice that the variables are not updated when you press "Stop button"

Comment: Yes..it's true..It supposed that the scanning will stop after the 'Stop' button is pressed but it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see much from the code snippet you shared; but
it seems like you forgot to set the **ismeasure**, and **isRecord** variable when you press the Stop button. In the code you already put in validation to make sure that the user will always Start -> Stop -> Insert, and not skip ahead any of the steps. But the variables to check are not all in place, changing a few of the variable names myself; we end up with something like:

```
Button startWifiScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
startWifiScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.groundTruth);
        CeLLiD = editText.getText().toString();
        if(CeLLiD.equals(""))
        {
            alert("Ground Truth is not Set");
        }
        else if(recording == true)
            alert("Scanning is already started!");
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi Scan started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            rssDatabase = dumpDataToHashmap(1);
            sdDatabase = dumpDataToHashmap(0);
            onResume();
            //recording = true means that you are scanning
            recording = true;
            //finished_recording = true means that you already finished recording
            finished_recording = false;
        }}
});

Button stopWifiScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);
stopWifiScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi Scan stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(recording == false) alert("Start Scanning!");
        else {

            //update the variables
            recording = false;
            finished_recording = true;

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Testing" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second+":"+CeLLiD);
            folder.mkdir();
            String csv = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/data.csv";
            try { file_writer = new FileWriter(csv, true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            onStop(); }
    }
});

Button insert= (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertbutton);
insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(recording == true)
            alert("Stop Scanning!");
        else if(recording == false && finished_recording == false) alert("Start Scanning!");
        else if(recording == false && finished_recording == true) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saving.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                writeToCsv();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            //something happened
        }
    }
});
}
```

Now the problem is that I hope that the csv file name/path is passed correctly so that after you press insert, the program can correctly find the file and fill it with data; I see that there's a **file_writer** variable but I don't see it being used other than the "writeToCsv" function; so do keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks, Sir, now it's working fine. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Reyha consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer then.